# Completely regular vs regular

Tags: general-topology

I know that regularity doesn't imply completely regular; however, does completely regular imply regularity?

I assume it does but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

It does. If we have a closed $A$ and a point $x \notin A$, then a continuous function $f \colon X \to [0,1]$ with $f(x) = 1$ and $f(A) \subset \{0\}$ provides separating open sets $U = f^{-1}((\frac23,1])$ and $V = f^{-1}([0,\frac13))$ with $U\cap V = \varnothing$, $x \in U$, and $A \subset V$.